# File Dual Status tax with one W-2

Tags: taxes, non-resident, form-w-2, resident

I worked for a US company for the whole year but only became resident alien in May. How should I file tax as dual status? Should I split the amount on W2 between 1040 and 1040-NR, and then attach a statement explain how I split the amount? How should I split the tax withholding between the two forms?

Comment: How did you determine that you "only became resident alien in May"? If you pass the Substantial Presence Test or Green Card Test for the year, you are a resident alien for the whole year, unless the First Year of Residency rules apply? Do the First Year of Residency rules apply in your case? Were you present in the US the whole year or only came to the US in May?